# How to share files between jobs in Azure Pipeline?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, share, publish

I want to share the files between jobs in azure pipeline. I know that one method of doing this is using `PublishPipelineArtifact` task. Is there any other method of doing the same?

I am using Azure DevOps Services and using a Linux machine as a self-hosted agent.

Answer (score 0):

Another way that has the similar functions is using the [Cache task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/cache-v2?view=azure-pipelines).

From the original intent, the **Cache** task and **PublishPipelineArtifact** task (or the old **PublishBuildArtifacts** task) are designed for different scenarios.

- Use **pipeline artifacts** when you need to take specific files produced in one job and share them with other jobs (and these other jobs will likely fail without them).
- Use **pipeline caching** when you want to improve build time by reusing files from previous runs (and not having these files won't impact the job's ability to run).

Of course, in some scenarios, you could use any of these tasks to pass files between jobs based on your actual use cases.

For more details about Cache, you can reference "[**Pipeline caching**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/caching?view=azure-devops)".

Answer (score -1):

Alternative is PublishBuildArtifacts task

Reference [link](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-devops-docs/issues/2341#issuecomment-439483135) to see difference on PublishPipelineArtifact
& PublishBuildArtifact

Answer (score -1):

1. It would be a good choice to use [PublishPipelineArtifact](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/publish-pipeline-artifact-v1?view=azure-pipelines) task (or [PublishBuildArtifacts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/publish-build-artifacts-v1?view=azure-pipelines) task) to publish files as a named artifact. Then consume the files using [DownloadPipelineArtifact](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/download-pipeline-artifact-v2?view=azure-pipelines) task (or [DownloadBuildArtifacts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/download-build-artifacts-v1?view=azure-pipelines) task) in other jobs/pipelines. Would you please let me know why you want to use other methods?
2. If you want to store and share large files, you can use [Storage account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-account-overview). Run [az storage blob upload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/storage/blob?view=azure-cli-latest#az-storage-blob-upload) in [Azure CLI task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/azure-cli-v2?view=azure-pipelines) to upload a file to a storage blob. Run [az storage blob download](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/storage/blob?view=azure-cli-latest#az-storage-blob-download) to download files from storage account.

There may be other methods to share files. You need to choose based on your actual needs.